# Node.js/q why this function doesn't get called?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, deferred, q

I've this code:

```
/**
 * On message received
 */
socket.on('message', function (message) {
    global.logger.info('%s : message : %s', address.address, message);
    execute(message, socket)
        .then(function (value) {
            global.logger.debug('%s : success : %s', address.address, value);
            socket.emit('message', message);
        }, function (error) {
            global.logger.debug('%s : fail : %s', address.address, error);
            socket.emit('error', error);
        });
});

function execute(message, socket) {
    global.logger.debug('Got here : %s', message);
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    deferred.reject(new Error('test'));
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

But when i run and send a message to socket.io, the only line i can see in the log is this one:

```
info: 93.xxx.xxx.xxx : message : lalalalala
```

how this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My error!
I had set the logger level at "info"

Now the log is:

```
info: 93.147.76.106 : message : stupid
info: Got here : stupid
info: 93.147.76.106 : fail : %s
```

i **do not** deserve that upvote O_o